# How to integrate API in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on react project. In my application In navigation bar I am displaying menu's. Here I want to display some text or message. This message has to be loaded from the API during the page load. Below is my code.

```
const NavigationBar = ({ className }) => (
  <div className={className}>
    <NavigationBarSection>
      <NavigationTitle to="/">
        <ReactSVG path={ipmLogoUrl} style={{ width: 24 }} />
      </NavigationTitle>
      <NavigationItem exact to="/">
        Import
      </NavigationItem>
      <NavigationItem to="/timephase">Timephase</NavigationItem>
      <NavigationItem to="/sync-progress">Sync Progress</NavigationItem>
      <NavigationItem to="/parameters">Parameters</NavigationItem>
    </NavigationBarSection>
    <div>I want to display message from API</div>
    <NavigationBarSection>
      <Dropdown
        label={
          <BlockNavigationItem>
            <Icon icon={<Help />} />
          </BlockNavigationItem>
        }
      >
        <DropdownItem
          target="_blank"
          href="/api/replenishment-parameters/keycode-parameters-template"
        >
          Download D&F Keycode Template
        </DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem
          target="_blank"
          href="/api/replenishment-parameters/sims-keycode-parameters-template"
        >
          Download SIMS Keycode Template
        </DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem
          target="_blank"
          href="/api/replenishment-parameters/timephase-template"
        >
          Download Timephase Template
        </DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
          target="_blank"
          href="https://kmartonline.atlassian.net/wiki/x/5ICICg"
        >
          Help and Support
        </DropdownItem>
      </Dropdown>

      <UserProfile />
    </NavigationBarSection>
  </div>
);
```

Can someone help me to complete this? Any help would be appropriated.  Thanks

Comment: There are various http request library out there you can use any one such as, axios, request, and fetch is the default http request handler

Comment: Thanks. Can you share me examples?

Comment: This is a pen on codepen by Jon Vadillo check this out:-https://codepen.io/jonvadillo/pen/eRvdar

Comment: I need example on functional component

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vfbdr7?file=functionalComponent.js

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/j24632p4rw

Answer (score 0):

I have created a project using axios and reactjs , please check on [GITHUB](https://github.com/eravinashm/axios-reactjs-app)

Snippet from the project:-

> GET CALL

```
   axios.get('/posts')
        .then(response => {
            const posts = response.data.splice(0, 4);
            const updatedPosts = posts.map(post => {
                return{
                    ...post,
                    author: 'Max'
                }    
            });
            this.setState({posts: updatedPosts});
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            // this.setState({error: true});
        })
```

> POST CALL

```
let data = {
    title: this.state.title,
    body: this.state.body,
    author: this.state.author
}
axios.post('/posts', data)
    .then(response => {
        // console.log(response)
        // this.props.history.push('/posts');
        this.props.history.replace('/posts');
        // this.setState({submitted: true});
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

For your question, [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) the default standard. Node.JS also has a built-in request handler called **Fetch API** and you can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

---

## How each one works:

**Fetch API:**

[image: fetch-api-get-call]

**Axios:**

[image: axios-get-call]

---

## Differences:

### 1. With axios you automatically get a JSON Object.

If you wanted a JSON response when calling with Fetch, you would need to pass it to `.json()` first:

```
fetch('https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers/1')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(data));
```

Axios already does that for you.

### 2. Axios does a better job handling errors:

Let's say you called the fetch API with a wrong URL:

[image]

The request returned a 400 error, but Fetch API still logged the data.

Now let's try axios:

[image]

This is way better! I get the error I was expecting and I didn't get the empty data back.

### 3. Monitoring POST requests:

Axios allows you to monitor POST requests:

Let's say that you sent a request but it is taking too much. With Fetch you won't know if it is just slow or if your code is broken. Axios allows you to monitor your requests.

```
axios.post('https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers/1', data, {
  onUploadProgress: ({ total, loaded }) => {
    // Update progress
  },
});
```

---

## Axios with React Components:

Here is a great tutorial on the subject: [Using Axios with React](https://alligator.io/react/axios-react/).

Basically, you define a function inside your component, which uses Axios and then you call it wherever you need that functionality. For a GET request it would be most suitable to call `axios.get()` in `componentDidMount()`. For other requests, you would define a separate function.

---

## Summary:

There are many other aspects of Axios and its advantages over Fetch and there are also other packages similar to Axios. You might want to install it and play around with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-fetch-hook](https://github.com/ilyalesik/react-fetch-hook) for this. Like this:

```js
const NavigationBar = ({ className }) => {
  const {data: message} = useFetch("<api_url_for_message>");
  return <div className={className}>
    ...
    <div>{message}</div>
    ...
  </div>
}
```

React 16.8.0 is needed.